# How to migrate to the new angular2 router and forms?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-forms

After developing with angular2 beta for a while, I started to get warnings that im using a deprecated version of forms. More than that some css packages like primeng were broken after the deprection of the angular/router.

Is there any simple way to migrate from angular2 beta to the new rc forms and router?

Im struggling with errors like

> No value accessor for ''

and

> No provider for Router!

Answer (score 3):

I found [this great article](https://medium.com/@blacksonic86/upgrading-to-the-new-angular-2-router-255605d9da26#.79ci9sif2) about migrating to the new angular router from the deprecated one.
here are the basics:

## Router:

### config:

deprecated:

```
@RouteConfig([
  {path: '/',name: 'Heroes',component: Heroes,useAsDefault: true},
  {path: '/detail/:id',name: 'HeroDetail',component: HeroDetailComponent}
])

bootstrap(AppComponent, [
  ROUTER_PROVIDERS
]);
```

will become:

```
const appRoutes: RouterConfig = [
  { path: '', component: Heroes, terminal: true },
  { path: 'detail/:id', component: HeroDetailComponent }
];

bootstrap(RootComponent,[
  provideRouter(appRoutes)
]);
```

### linking:

deprecated:

```
<a [routerLink]="['/Heroes']">Heroes</a>
<a [routerLink]="['/HeroDetail', { id: 1 }]">Captain America</a>
```

will become:

```
<a [routerLink]="['']">Heroes</a>
<a [routerLink]="['detail', 1]">Captain America</a>
```

### route params:

deprecated:

```
export class HeroDetailComponent {
  constructor(private params: RouteParams) {
    let idParam = params.get("id");
  }
}
```

will become:

```
export class HeroDetailComponent {
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {
    let idParam = route.params._value.id;
  }
}
```

***you should import everything new from "@angular/router".***

And for the forms migration, this worked for me:

## Forms

deprecated:

```
@Component({
    selector: "my-form",
    directives: [FORM_DIRECTIVES]
})
export class MyFormPage{
    myForm: ControlGroup;
/* rest of the class */
}
```

will become:

```
@Component({
    selector: "my-form",
    directives: [REACTIVE_FORM_DIRECTIVES]
})

export class MyFormPage{
    myForm: FormGroup;
/* rest of the class */
}
```

deprecated:

```
<form [ngFormModel]="myForm" #f="ngForm" (submit)="submitForm(f.value)">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Name</label>
        <input type="text" ngControl="name">
    </div>
</form>
```

will become:

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm" (ngSubmit)="submitForm(myForm.value)">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Name</label>
        <input type="text" formControlName="name">
    </div>
</form>
```

***you should import everything new from "@angular/forms".***